# How can I perform a floating point multiplication in assembly without using mul

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips, multiplication

I'm trying to perform a floating point number multiplication in assembly code but without using a mul instruction. Based on the concept of multiplication, A*B is A added B number of times but I don't see how that would be possible using floating points.

This is how I wrote a code for a simple integer multiplication. `t6` is a counter initialized to 0 and `t0` is the value of B in this case. `t1` would be A:

```
Loop1:
    bge $t6, $t0, ExitL1 # If value of t6 is greater or equal than t0, exit
    add $t1, $t1, $t0    # Adds value of t0 to t1 and stores in t1
    addi $t6, $t6, 1     # Increases loop counter by 1
    j Loop1
```

Comment: The MIPS `mul` instruction does integer multiply.  Did you mean [`mul.s` for single-precision FP multiply](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node20.html)? Normally for software floating point you would want to use an integer multiply instruction on the mantissas (aka significands), probably `mult` so you can get the high half of the result.

Comment: Anyway, repeated addition using `add.s` would have massive problems with rounding errors, even if you only had integer-valued floats.  e.g. for large enough inputs, `x -= 1` is still equal to `x`.  So using a float as a loop counter would get stuck in an infinite loop for some inputs.  I assume this is for a homework assignment or something where you're supposed to implement software floating point using integer operations?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format and [How are floating point operations emulated in software?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39810751)

Comment: Also [Software Floating Point (Howto)](//stackoverflow.com/q/4964466) and http://flip.gforge.inria.fr/ are examples of C implementations.  Do you need to produce IEEE-754 compliant results, i.e. correctly rounded down to the last bit of the mantissa?  And handling subnormals and NaNs?  If not you could probably simplify vs. what some implementations do.